# Calculate Assist Percentage in basketball

Tags: statistics, basketball, nba

On Basketball Reference they state that

> Assist Percentage; the formula is 100 * AST / (((MP / (Team MP / 5)) * Team FG) - FG). Assist percentage is an estimate of the percentage of teammate field goals a player assisted while he was on the floor.

If you take a game from the [NBA](https://watch.nba.com/game/20170409/OKCDEN) and look at Russell Westbrook for example.

[MP=36, AST=10, FG=17](https://watch.nba.com/game/20170409/OKCDEN)

[Team FG=40, Team MP= 48](https://stats.nba.com/teams/traditional/?sort=FGM&dir=-1&Season=2016-17&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&OpponentTeamID=1610612743&DateFrom=04%2F09%2F2017&DateTo=04%2F09%2F2017&TeamID=1610612760)

So using the formula I do

100 * 10 / (((36 / (48 / 5)) * 40) - 17)

Which equals 7.519

But on the [NBA stats site](https://stats.nba.com/players/usage/?sort=USG_PCT&dir=-1&Season=2016-17&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&OpponentTeamID=1610612743&DateFrom=04%2F09%2F2017&DateTo=04%2F09%2F2017) it comes back with 58.8.

Have I done something wrong with the calculation here or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why NBA stats shows Russell Westbrook assist percentage as 58.8 because *[basketball-reference stats](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201704090DEN.html)* for the same game shows **72.5**.

From *[basketball-reference,](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/201704090DEN.html)* stats for Russell Westbrook and team for that match,

MP=37, AST=10, FG=17, Team FG=40, Team MP= 240

NBA stats shows Team MP as 48 which is obtained after dividing 240 by 5 i.e, (Team Mp / 5).

Using these stats we can get assist percentage around 72.5. For your calculation, if you use 48 for (Team MP / 5) and 37 for MP (Russel played 36 min 57 sec) you will get almost same data as basketball reference.

Comment: Thanks sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote it up. I think NBA must use a slightly different calculation, at least I know I can use the accurate minutes played per player